# Fluentbit Cloudwatch templating with EKS and Fargate

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, fluent-bit

I've an EKS cluster purely on Fargate and I'm trying to setup the logging to Cloudwatch.
I've a lot of [OUTPUT] sections that can be unified using some variables. I'd like to unify the logs of each deployment to a single `log_stream` and separate the `log_stream` by environment (name_space). Using a couple of variable I'd need just to write a single  [OUTPUT] section.

For what I understand the [new Fluentbit plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/cloudwatch): `cloudwatch_logs` doesn't support templating, but the [old plugin](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-for-fluent-bit) `cloudwatch`  does.

I've tried to setup a section like in the documentation example:

```
[OUTPUT]
      Name              cloudwatch
      Match             *container_name*
      region            us-east-1
      log_group_name    /eks/$(kubernetes['namespace_name'])
      log_stream_name   test_stream
      auto_create_group on
```

This generates a `log_group` called `fluentbit-default` that according to the README.md is the fallback name in case the variables are not parsed.

The old plugin `cloudwatch` is supported (but not mentioned in AWS documentation) because if I replace the variable `$(kubernetes['namespace_name'])` with any string it works perfectly.

Fluentbit in Fargate manages automatically the INPUT section so I don't really know which variables are sent to the OUTPUT section, I suppose the variable `kubernetes` is not there or it has a different name or a different array structure.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to get the list of the variables (or input) that Fargate + Fluentbit are generating?
- Get I solve that in a different way? (I don't want to write more than 30 different OUTPUT one for each service/log_stream_name. It would be also difficult to maintain it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of tests, I've realised that you need to enable the `kubernetes` filter to receive the `kubernetes` variables to the cloudwatch plugin.
This is the result, and now I can generate `log_group` depending on the environment label and `log_stream` depending of the container-namespace names.

```
filters.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match *
        Merge_Log Off
        Buffer_Size 0
        Kube_Meta_Cache_TTL 300s
  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match *
        region eu-west-2
        log_group_name /aws/eks/cluster/$(kubernetes['labels']['app.environment'])
        log_stream_name $(kubernetes['namespace_name'])-$(kubernetes['container_name'])
        default_log_group_name /aws/eks/cluster/others
        auto_create_group true
        log_key log
```

**Please note** that the `app.environment` is not a "standard" value, I've added it to all my deployments. The `default_log_group_name` is necessary in case that value is not present.

**Please note also** that if you use `log_retention_days` and `new_log_group_tags` the system is not going to work. To be honest `log_retention_days` it never worked for me also using the new `cloudwatch_logs` plugin either.